# In Django1.8 project, can't find static files in different application

Tags: django

I have started learning Django1.8.
In my project, I have 2 applications - one is `account app` and the other is `images app`. Each application directory contains **static** directory.

The static directory structures of 2 apps are as follows.

**account app**

```
static/
    css/
        base.css
```

**images app**

```
static/
    js/
        bookmarklet.js
    css/
        bookmarklet.css
```

When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/base.css` in `account app` on the browser, I can find `base.css` file on the browser.

But when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bookmarklet.js` in `images app`, I get 404 error.

> 'js\bookmarklet.js' could not be found

I'm not sure how can I fix this issue.

Comment: Try `./manage.py collectstaticfiles`.

Comment: Would you explain it for me in more detail?

Comment: Open Terminal, navigate to directory where your django project is (where `manage.py` is) and run above command. What this does is it goes through all apps, searches for static content and collects them into main `static` folder. Then the files become accessible. Make sure you have `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` in your `settings.py`. It comes by default, but check anyways. Take a look at [static files documantation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) as well.

Comment: When I run `$python manage.py collectstaticfiles`, I get error such as **Unknown command: 'collectstaticfiles'**.

Comment: Sorry, `collectstatic`, not `collectstaticfiles`. Since you are new to django I advise you to read documentation every time you don't know something. The documentation is really good and even if it does not answer your problem, you might learn something else that will come in handy in the future. Then of course search google if you didn't find the answer. I did the same. Reading docs for no reason is the key to learning django ;)

Comment: `$python manage.py collectstatic` is not working. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)...

Comment: Check the documantation link I gave you, check what `STATICFILES_DIRS` is used for. Also pay attention to `STATIC_ROOT`. I always go with `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')`.

Answer (score 0):

When I add `STATICFILES_DIRS` in `settings.py` file, I can fix this issue.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

Comment: Nice, you solved it in the moment I told you about `STATICFILES_DIRS` :D

Comment: well static_root is different form staticfiles_dirs. STATIC_ROOT is for specific the folder when you collectstatic, that save the static files of admin inside this folder